# Transferring 5 megabytes file using wcf

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to use wcf for transferring a file larger then 5 mega.(i cant use streeaming for now it demands major changes to running code).

I configured the server and the client to the maximum settings and still i get the exception of maximum length.

Here is my server web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
    logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
</diagnostics>
<services>
    <service name="xxx.xxx.Service">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="xxx"
            contract="xxx.xxx.IService" />
    </service>
</services>
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="b2bservice" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
            receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
            transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client />
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

And here is the client app.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="xxx"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
    contract="BService.IBService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
</client>
```

My trace Logging is:

> Maximum request length exceeded.
>   System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is the server IIS by any chance, or your own application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not resetting the default 4MB limit properly.

Try this: http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/01/29/retrieving-huge-amount-of-data-from-wcf-service-in-silverlight-application/

Answer (score 3):

Set `maxRequestLength` in `httpRuntime` section in Web.config

[HttpRuntime configuration element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to increase the max request length by changing the following setting in web.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="32768" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The value is in KB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730342.aspx) to get more details about your problem and fix it or give use exact error message.

Comment: i did, and i posted the exception in my question